# Pronunciation of 잘 - /jal/ or /jai/

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-korean

I am wondering about the pronunciation of Korean sentence before eating below.

> 잘 먹겠습니다 - (Jal moke get sum nida)

I am confused about the pronunciation of 잘. Is it /jal/ or /jai/? As I learned ㄹ should be pronounced as /l/ in that place. However, from what I heard it is really much more similar to /i/ sound than /l/ sound. 
 Is that because of me hearing it wrong or there is something about the pronunciation that I haven't known yet?

Comment: Sometimes the speaker is being sloppy and dropping the 'L' sound. I believe this also happens with 'all right'--which then sounds like 'aright.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

잘 is /t͜ɕal/. /jal/ would be 얄. Remember, /j/ is a "**y**es"-sound, not a ㅈ sound.

That being said, the reason why you're hearing /l/ as [i] or [j] is probably because the Korean /l/ at the end of a syllable tends to be [realized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_%28linguistics%29) as [ɭ], a [retroflex lateral approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_lateral_approximant). That means it's articulated with the tip of the tongue curled up. That is close to how [j] is articulated, so I suppose you can confuse it with a [j]. But keep in mind, /l/ is never realized as [j].

Answer (score 1):

I never find [i] sound in 잘. The two sounds are fairly different. I think it's because the pronunciation system is totally different between Korean and English.

If you are sure to hear [i] sound. I guess, there is [i] sound that Koreans can't catch. Actually, I have some English sounds that I can't catch when I listen to English.

Anyways, as Korean aspect, [ㄹ] and [i] are totally different. Especially, [ㄹ] is a consonant and [i] is a vowel.

Listen one more in google translate.